# Nginx not serving static files with Waitress+Django on Windows

Tags: python, django, nginx, waitress

I have installed django 2.0 on a virtualenv with python 3.4 and because gunicorn cannot be installed in windows i found waitress that is ok with his work, mi problem is that nginx (probably a bad configuration by my part) is not serving the static files but i do not find to much about nginx on windows.

This is my settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4e&6aw+(5&cg^_!05r(&7_#dghg_pdgopq(yk)xa^bog7j)^*j'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myip','mydomain.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apáname'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'helloworld.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'helloworld.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

This is my nginx.conf :

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    access_log "logs/nginx-access.log";
    error_log "logs/nginx-error.log";

    location /static/ {
        alias "C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configuration-Server/static/";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And this is how i run waitress by cmd prompt in virtualenv:

```
waitress --serve listen="*:8000 myprojectname.wsgi:application
```

Comment: And the URL with the issue is? Error message/response/status is?

Comment: when i use http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/ it works but when i use http://myapp.com:8000/myapp/ doesnt work and i get this message: `WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /static/js/sweetalert2.all.min.js
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /favicon.ico`

Comment: Perhaps this is totally nginx question. You config is serving only "localhost", no domain names. Try `server_name myapp.com`.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
location /static/ {
        alias "C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configuration-Server/static/";
    }
```

for:

```
location /static/ {
        alias C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configuration-Server/static;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

waitress-serve listen="*:8000 myprojectname.wsgi:application